# Java8 - How do you manipulate and assign a variable?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `Map<Enum, Object> myMap` and I'm trying to simplify this condition with Java8 `Optional`. If it is possible, how do you do it? My goal is to assign `newVar`

```
Enum2 newVar = Z;
if(myMap.containsKey(A))
  newVar = X;
if(myMap.containsKey(B))
  newVar = Y;
```

Comment: Could you fix(map does not have `contains` method) your question and provide more life example. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you have quite many such branches (otherwise your code is simple enough and no changes are necessary). In this case it's better to create a predefined map `Map<Enum,Enum2>`:

```
// initialized once statically
Map<Enum,Enum2> enum2map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
enum2map.put(A, X);
enum2map.put(B, Y);
...
```

Then you can use it in the following way (using `Optional` as you want):

```
Enum2 newVar = enum2map.entrySet().stream()
                       .filter(e -> myMap.containsKey(e.getKey()))
                       .findFirst()
                       .map(e -> e.getValue()).orElse(Z);
```

Comment: I think that's what @dkulkarni was looking for.

Comment: Yup. This works. My map contains many keys. So I would prefer this approach over if-else

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional operator.

```
newVar = myMap.contains(B) ? Y : myMap.contains(A) ? X : Z;
```

For more information, you can check the official information in [Equality, Relational, and Conditional Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Is there a way to simplify it with Optional?

Comment: I'm sorry, understood that. I think it is not possible, for what I've found. As far as the javadoc says, Optional<T> is _a container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return the value._ That means, the only thing you could do with optional is finding out whether something contains something else or it does not, creating even more conditions and variables (therefore being less memory-friendly) just to find out the same result.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. The correct one is: newVar = myMap.contains(B) ? Y : myMap.contains(A) ? X : Z; (A and B, X and Y must be inverted)

Comment: Oh wow I'm sorry. Didn't really pay much attention to where each var was, just wrote them down randomly. Will edit now, thanks!